# Using FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I use FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE and the function I want to call comes without any problems and I can perform my operations there. But when I close the function I called, it does not run the codes below where I called the function. How can I make it run those codes?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't know; FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE is related to Oracle E-Business Suite (which I never used). However: as it is about **Forms**, try to run form (the *caller*) in debug mode so that you'd be able to follow its execution. If Forms version you use doesn't have debugger (6i and below), you'll have to do it manually (by including MESSAGE built-in calls throughout form triggers and procedures). In this case, that's probably only one trigger - the one that calls FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE.

Comment: Hello littlefoot. I tried what you said. Message before FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE work but mesaage after FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE not working. I don't have any condition . I'm using 6i . What do you recommend for calling another form.

Comment: Documentation says that - in EBS - you shouldn't use CALL_FORM, OPEN_FORM nor NEW_FORM, but what you actually do: FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE. Unfortunately, I have no idea why code that follows it won't execute. Perhaps you should share actual code you use (the whole trigger). Also, how do you terminate that "other" form?

Comment: I add my code as an image.